# RNN Training Loss Goes Down Then Acts Erratically

Tags: python, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation, data-loss

I've been trying to create a vanilla 3 layer RNN in Python 3.6, but whenever I train it the training loss decreases for the first X amount of training iterations then goes up and down sporadically and I can't identify the problem. I don't want to use Tensorflow or Keras or any deep learning framework for now because I'm trying to get a better understanding of how these NNs work.

I'm pretty sure my problem lies either in the way I added matrices together in my forward prop function, or in my get error and weight update part of my backprop function so I will post them both below.

Sorry if my code is a bit messy but here is my function that forward props through my neural network.

```
def RNN_forward(self, A):

    #input layer
    self.A = A

    #self.AB is a-b weight matrix
    self.B1 = np.dot(self.A, self.AB)

    #self.B_t is self.B (layer 2) from the previous timestep
    self.B_t1 = np.dot(self.B_t, self.B_RNN)

    #combining matrices
    self.B = self.sigmoid((self.B1) + (self.B_t1))
    self.C1 = np.dot(self.B, self.BC)

    #output layer
    self.C = self.sigmoid(self.C1) 
    return self.C
```

My backprop and update weight matrix functions are mushed into one function, sorry everything is so messy

```
def RNN_backprop(self, C_real):

    #did this so I could transpose a 1D matrix
    BT = self.B[np.newaxis]

    #get error of BC weight matrix
    delta3 = np.multiply(-(C_real-self.C), self.sigmoidPrime(self.C1))
    BCp = np.dot(BT.T, delta3)
    BCpT = BCp[np.newaxis]

    #get error of AB weight matrix
    delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.BC.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.B1) 
    AT, d2 = self.A[np.newaxis], delta2[np.newaxis]
    ABp = np.dot(AT.T, d2)

    #get error of weight matrix linked to previous time step
    delta2t = np.dot(delta3, self.BC.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.B_t1) 
    B_RNNT, d2t = self.B_t[np.newaxis], delta2t[np.newaxis]
    B_RNNp = np.dot(B_RNNT.T, d2t)

    #training speed
    weight_multiplier = 10

    #update weight matricies
    self.BC = self.BC - BCpT.T*weight_multiplier 
    self.AB = self.AB - ABp*weight_multiplier 
    self.B_RNN = self.B_RNN - B_RNNp*weight_multiplier             

    #store layer 2 to be used in next timestep
    self.B_t = self.B
```

I am happy to post the entire code or any other bits that anyone might need to help diagnose my problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice or potential solutions you might have!

Edit:  Here is the entire code: it is really poorly commented so it's going to be difficult to read it but its all here. Some lines are commented out just because I wasn't sure if I was going to try and use them or not.

import numpy as np

class NN(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.A_size = 4
    self.B_size = 6
    self.C_size = 1

def init_weights(self):
    self.AB = np.random.randn(self.A_size, self.B_size)
    self.BC = np.random.randn(self.B_size, self.C_size)
    self.B_t = [0]
    self.B_RNN = np.random.randn(self.B_size, self.B_size)

def sigmoid(self, X1):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-X1))

def sigmoidPrime(self,X1):
    return np.exp(-X1)/((1+np.exp(-X1))**2)

def print_status(self, NN_type):
    print("---------Status---------")
    print("A: ", self.A)
    print("AB: ", self.AB)
    print("B: ", self.B)
    print("BC: ", self.BC)
    print("C: ", self.C)
    if NN_type == "RNN":
        print("Previous B: ", self.B_t)
    if NN_type == "LSTM":
        pass        
    #print("Error: ", self.cost)
    print("---------Done---------")

def RNN_forward(self, A):
    self.A = A
    self.B1 = np.dot(self.A, self.AB)
    if len(self.B_t) > 2:
        self.B_t1 = np.dot(self.B_t, self.B_RNN)
        self.B = self.sigmoid((self.B1) + (self.B_t1))
        #self.B = self.sigmoid(np.tanh(self.B1) + np.tanh(self.B_t1))
    else:
        self.B = self.sigmoid(self.B1)
        self.B_t = self.B
        self.B_t1 = np.dot(self.B_t, self.B_RNN)
        print('this should only print once')
    self.C1 = np.dot(self.B, self.BC)
    self.C = self.sigmoid(self.C1) 
    return self.C

def skip_backprop(self):
    self.B_t = self.B

def get_cost(self, C_real):
    #self.cost = 0.5*sum((C_real-self.C)**2)
    self.cost = 0.5*((C_real-self.C)**2)
    return self.cost

def RNN_backprop(self, C_real):
    BT = self.B[np.newaxis]
    delta3 = np.multiply(-(C_real-self.C), self.sigmoidPrime(self.C1))
    BCp = np.dot(BT.T, delta3)
    BCpT = BCp[np.newaxis]

    delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.BC.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.B1) 
    AT, d2 = self.A[np.newaxis], delta2[np.newaxis]
    ABp = np.dot(AT.T, d2)

    delta2t = np.dot(delta3, self.BC.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.B_t1) 
    B_RNNT, d2t = self.B_t[np.newaxis], delta2t[np.newaxis]
    B_RNNp = np.dot(B_RNNT.T, d2t)

    #Important
    #weight_multiplier = 5 * (np.sum(np.absolute(ABp))+np.sum(np.absolute(BCpT))+np.sum(np.absolute(B_RNNp)))
    weight_multiplier = 0.01

    self.BC = self.BC - BCpT.T*weight_multiplier 
    self.AB = self.AB - ABp*weight_multiplier 
    self.B_RNN = self.B_RNN - B_RNNp*weight_multiplier             

    self.B_t = self.B

NN = NN()
NN.init_weights()

#important
iterations = 100000    
for a in range(iterations):
    total_error = 0
    for i in range(50):
        NN.RNN_forward(np.array(As[i]))
        NN.RNN_backprop(C_reals[i])
        total_error += NN.get_cost(C_reals[i])
    if a%500 == 0:    
        print("Error: ",total_error)
NN.RNN_forward(np.array([1,1,1,0.2]))
NN.skip_backprop()
print("0.4: ", NN.RNN_forward(np.array([1,1,1,0.3])))
NN.RNN_forward(np.array([1,1,1,0.4]))
NN.skip_backprop()
print("0.2: ", NN.RNN_forward(np.array([1,1,1,0.3])))
```

Comment: self.B_RNN is not defined before you use it in the first code block. In the second code block, is weight_multiplier supposed to be your learning rate? Usually learning rates are much smaller, like 1e2 or smaller

Comment: self.B_RNN is defined when I create an instance of the class, and I've been playing around with different learning rates but they all seem to have the same problem. I will test some much smaller learning rates though and see if it helps!

Comment: Because this isn't a fully functioning piece of code, it's difficult to examine to try to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I posted the entire code for you to look at if you'd like. Also I changed the learning rate to 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, and 1 and had the same problem with all 4.

Comment: Why are you calling NN.RNN_forward(np.array(As[i])) and then immediately calling NN.RNN_backprop(C_reals[i]) ? Usually I think RNNs have 1 target per sequence. You forward propagate an entire sequence of inputs (think of a sentence) and then when you're done, you backpropagate. But you only have 1 target for the whole sequence (like a label for a sentence). Is this some other use case? If so, please specify exactly what type of problem you're solving

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to eliminate this kind of behavior is to reduce the learning rate as you continue training. 
While I can't explain it, adding batch normalization helped me to solve this problem in one case. But I could later get rid of it after increasing the capacity of the network.

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me so far. My new learning rate is defined by: learning_rate = ( ( 2000 / float(iteration_number) ** (1. / 3) ) + (iterations / 1000 ) ) / iterations where iterations is the total training iterations and iteration_number is the iteration that it is on.